# Reading a text file into a one dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, text-files

I have been given the passenger list with passengers names, which represents the passengers currently waiting in the waiting room (which is an array).

Currently, I am struggling with some parts of step 1.                                   The pseudocode is as follows:

1. Read in the passengers.dat file into the waitingRoom array.

Here is my code:

```
    public class TrainStation {
    int WAITING_ROOM_CAPACITY = 30;

       static Passenger[] waitingRoom = new Passenger[WAITING_ROOM_CAPACITY]; 

       static PassengerQueue queue = new PassengerQueue();

       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       //1. 
            try {
            File pointFile = new File ("passenger.dat");
            Scanner pointReader = new Scanner (pointFile);
            String firstName, surname;
            int i = 0;
            while (pointReader.hasNext()) {
                firstName = pointReader.next();
                surname = pointReader.next();
                Passenger Object = new Passenger(firstName, surname);
                waitingRoom[i] = Object;
                i++;
            }   
                for (int fori=0; fori<WAITING_ROOM_CAPACITY; fori++){
                System.out.println(waitingRoom[fori]); }
            pointReader.close();

          } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, file not found");  
          }
```

My WAITING_ROOM_CAPACITY can only hold 30 passengers
I created two arrays. One array is for the waitingRoom and the other one for the trainQueue. I tried to read the file using the Scanner and following the pseudocode by converting the Passenger class into an object, however, I keep getting "example.Passenger@6bc7c054" rather than reading the actual names of the passengers from the file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTsY3.png)

In addition to this, I have two classes:

```
package trainstation;


public class Passenger {
    private String firstName; 
    private String surname;
    private int secondsInQueue;

    Passenger(String firstName, String surname) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.surname = surname; 
        secondsInQueue = 0;
    }
```

This is my Passenger Class, where I allow within my add method to add a passenger with their names and surnames.

Could someone please help as I am really struggling.

Comment: Please check out the [ask] for more on how to improve this and your future questions

Comment: Try breaking down each of those steps into separate methods.  (This is a basic technique sometimes called "divide and conquer".)  Then figure out what is not working with each step and ask a question about just that step.

Comment: Regarding, "I tried to read the (passenger.dat) file using the Scanner and following the pseudocode by converting the Passenger class into an object, however, I keep getting some errors." -- ***what*** errors? The error messages are of extreme importance. Again, please read the [ask] as it will tell you this.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [How do I print my Java object without getting “SomeType@2f92e0f4”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I print my Java object without getting "SomeType@2f92e0f4"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can add Errors, Logs and anything your console outputs as well as text as your code snippets.

If an error does not clearly state, info, warning, error or exception, it is neither of those.

What I see by your picture is just a String representation of your Passenger entry in your array.

I try to clarify:

Passenger is an object. By `System.out.println(passenger);` you just tell your compiler that you want to print that passenger, but your compiler cant say what you want to print exactly, so it tells you what it is. A `Passenger` created by `example` with an hexnumber for identification. It doesn't know you want to print that String which is only a PART of that object, even if its propably 99% of that object.

Ok, now how to fix it, quite easily, in your Passenger class just add:

```
public String toString() { 
   return this.firstName + "," + this.surname;
}
```

Because that System.out.println() will just use the `toString()` method to print.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [How do I print my Java object without getting “SomeType@2f92e0f4”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)

Comment: Better to vote as a duplicate than to answer it. To wit -- please compare your answer to the ones in the duplicate and tell which ones are more helpful to future visitors with  a similar problem?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels how does one _vote as a duplicate_ ? (Please pardon my ignorance.)